# How to convert the current date/time to a format which selenium IDE understnad and vice versa

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I have to automate a web application scenario using selenium a automation tool where a calander is involved. When i recorded the scenario having a calander (Current time) then the selenium tool itself stores the current date/time in a different format. When i tried to play back the same recorded scenario then i got stucked there. The reason is that the current time is already past while playing back the recorded scenario.

Could you please help me out in converting the date/time to a selenium friendly format and vice versa so that i may be able to set the dynamic value for the date/time in my recorded script.

Answer (score 1):

You can store current date time with the following

```
<tr>
<td>storeExpression</td>
<td>javascript{var date = new Date();date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getFullYear() + '_' + date.getHours() + '_' + date.getMinutes() + '_' + date.getSeconds();}</td>
<td>date</td>
```

```
<tr>
<td>echo</td>
<td>${date}</td>
<td></td>
```

The result will be

`currentdate-currentmonth-currentyeaar_currenthours_currentminutes_currentseconds`

eg.`24-10-2013_11_9_11`

Let's say you don't want to got time if so the code will be change like that

`javascript{var date = new Date();date.getDate() + '-' + (date.getMonth()+1) + '-' + date.getFullYear() ;}`

So, The result will be `currentdate-currentmonth-currentyeaar`

eg.`24-10-2013`

I hope you can understand my answer.